# jQueryMobile: Open dialog and scroll to anchor

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to open a dialog with jQuery Mobile:

```
<a href="terms.html" data-rel="dialog" data-anchor="cancellationterms">
    Cancellation terms
</a>
```

I also tried appending `#cancellationterms` to the `href` attribute.
But then nothing happens.

How to get it scrolling to the specified anchor on the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this did the trick:

```
var anchor = '';
$('a[data-anchor]').live('click', function() {
    anchor = $(this).data('anchor');
});

$('div[data-role="dialog"]').live('pageshow', function(e, ui) {
    $('.ui-dialog-contain > .ui-content', this).scrollTo(jumpto);
});

$.fn.scrollTo = function(id) {
    var obj = $('#' + id);
    if (obj.length > 0) {
        $(this).scrollTop(obj.position().top);
    }
};
```